# Python: No Module named suds

Tags: python, suds

I have python 2.7.9 installed.
When I run my script, I get the following error:

```
from suds.client import client  
ImportError: No module named suds.client
```

So I downloaded the suds library from:

https://fedorahosted.org/releases/s/u/suds/python-suds-0.4.tar.gz

and extracted it and installed it using command (`python setup.py install`).
The installed suds file is placed in Directory `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` as `suds-0.4-py2.7.egg`.
But when i again run my script, I found the same error.

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Are you sure the installation is a success?

Comment: Have you set up pythonpath to the location of python?

Comment: Check whether `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` is listed in Python's path:  `import sys; print sys.path`

Comment: If you using pip run pip freeze and make sure your package is there

Comment: yes  sure, the installation is a success. and also the python path is set that's why i'm able to run python script from command prompt. correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: First, is there a reason you didn't use `pip` to install it?

Comment: Second, are you sure you only have one copy of Python on your machine?

Comment: Third, "also the python path is set that's why i'm able to run python script from command prompt. correct me if i'm wrong": You're wrong. That means you have some directory with `python.exe` in it on the system's `%PATH%`. That doesn't mean you have this site-packages directory on your Python's `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got, Actually I needed to extract this

> suds-0.4-py2.7.egg file.

After extracting , it will create a suds folder in the directory  *'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages*
It worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

My missing suds issue was resolved by using suds-jurko as a replacement for the original suds package.  Python 3.5.1